# Angular Velocity calculation

Tags: mathematical-physics, quaternions, rigid-transformation

I am trying to calculate the time derivative of the quaternion from the following paper: [Robotics and Biomimetics (ROBIO)](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6490966)

See equation 1 below:

$\displaystyle{\dot{q}(t)=\frac{1}{2}q(t)\circ\vec{\omega}'(t)}.$

I'm simulating a rigid body dynamics and I'm trying to find the angular velocity, the velocity, the acceleration and position.

How can i find the $ω$, angular velocity and the new position.

I know that: (Equation 2)

> $\omega_{average}=\dfrac{\Delta\theta}{\Delta t}$

**Equation 3**

[image: equation 3]

**Equation 4**

[image: equation 4]

Comment: Was the first equation given as the definition of $\dot q(t)$? What is the meaning of the circular symbol between $q(t)$ and $\omega'$?

Comment: @DavidK It describes the time derivative of vector c (which is the unit vector of a bar in the tensegrity system in the z-axis in bar’s reference frame). (Check equation 3).
This is to later on calculate the velocity for the end points (nodes) of the bar. After that it gives an equation for angular velocity ω in the form of: (Check equation 4) to calculate afterwards the Lagrangian.
Through the paper it doesn’t define how to calculate the derivative of quaternion so by the research I made, I found the equation 1. I don’t know to calculate the derivative of quaternion.